# Why is the duration of transition always fixed with webkit browsers?

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, css-transitions

I've been playing around with CSS transition and made this **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aniskhan001/q0m3p73u/1)**

The `transition` property is currently supported by all the major browsers and doesn't require vendor prefixes either *(however I have included them in my fiddle)*. I have also searched on [W3C site](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-transitions/#transition-duration-property) for some known issue with `transition-duration` and didn't find any.

**HTML**

```
<div class="foo"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.foo {
    background: #4FC093;
    display: block;
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 300px inset;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 10s ease;
}

.foo:hover {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 50px inset; 
}
```

### The problem with Google Chrome / webkit browsers

> If I remove the cursor earlier before the transition ends, it goes back to it's initial state by taking (**`10s`**) the duration defined in the transition property.
>
> **For example :**
>   
> I removed the cursor after transition played for **`1s`** it goes back to it's initial state by taking **`10s`**.
>
> In Firefox and IE10+, the duration of changing back to it's initial state ***is the same*** duration of actual transition playing time.

To see it in action hover over to the `.foo` div and remove the cursor quickly when the transition starts.
*[ P.S: The duration of `10s` might be boring but I have made this to observe the issue clearly. ]*

Comment: As far as I know, this is new behavior with Chrome. They also just pushed an update out to M37, so it could be a new issue with that release...definitely weird.

Comment: I am using Windows and unable to test it on Safari. But the latest version of Opera also giving this weird output.

Comment: FWIW, I just tested on Safari and it has the same behavior.

Comment: So the problem is with all the webkit browsers.

Comment: That's what it looks like. Might be a pain, but you could animate it with jQuery rather than use CSS.

Comment: This is from the w3c: `... If the outgoing and incoming transitions are executed using their specified durations and timing functions, the resulting effect can be distractingly asymmetric because the second transition takes the full specified time to move a shortened distance. Instead, the expected behavior is that the second transition is shorter.` [Here is the link](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-transitions/#reversing)

Comment: @NicoO Thanks for the link. Read the para. So, "**the expected behavior is that the second transition is shorter**". Will it going to be the standard? Then webkit doesn't following the standard. But.. I can see it's passing most of tests in that link.

Comment: I don't want to pollute the comments for futher good ones, but yes: I think Chrome is not showing the desired behaviour. We could discuss what the *right* behaviour would be, since it's also a nice feature to have a guaranteed transition runtime. But this sure feels unnatural at this point. And i think Firefox is doing a better job here. The shown behaviour could become an optional timing function, but hopefully not the default.

Comment: I have never experienced this bug before. All my transitions are working smoothly in webkit. Weird.

Comment: @MindlessRanger which browser are you using? And my question was not about smoothness, but about the duration.

Comment: I am using chrome 36. And I understand your problem. I just can't find how to tell it. And I find why I haven't experienced this before: I am using *{transition-duration:500ms;}. Maybe that was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a second transition to make the "revert" animation faster for all (if that works for what you want).

See the [updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/q0m3p73u/8/) and partial CSS below:

```
.foo {
    /* default properties */
    transition: all 1s ease;/* this transition will apply when user exits hover state */
}

.foo:hover {
    /* properties for hover */
    transition: all 10s ease;/* this transition will apply when user hovers */
}
```

Comment: But it reverts to it's initial state within `1s`, which is not desired.

Comment: The problem with this is if you hover so it goes all the way in then it only takes 1 second to go back to its original size. Which just reverses the problem.

Comment: Yes - this is a solution which could be useful in some people's implementations. I will see if there is a way to exploit this to provide the exact workaround you desire.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't experienced this before, but I think I can see what is happening.

If I understand your problem correctly this is because when you hover initially, and remove before the transition is complete, chrome sees it as having to transition a small change in the same period of time so it appears slower.

For example, if you hover over your 600px diameter circle for 1 second and the diameter reaches 500px (just making that up) then when you stop hovering it only has to expand back by 100px over 10s not the full 500px it was calculating on the initial hover. Therefore the speed is decreased.

A sure fire way of doing this is by doing it with Javascript instead of CSS. That way you can calculate its current size on mouse leave and therefore keep the speed of transition constant.

Comment: I don't want to use JS. I'm fighting for CSS3 actually ;) 
It should be standardize and should works the same across all different browsers.

Comment: I agree, I will always try and use CSS over JS where I can. You could just use JS to change the transition time. Leave the actual transition down to the CSS.

Comment: I found this link which may help setting time in the DOM? http://www.programering.com/a/MjM4YzMwATg.html